# ClassCastException when getting bean from Spring app context, but not when Autowiring

Tags: java, spring, casting

I don't get this, I have a typical messageSource

```
<bean id="resource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>content.Language</value> 
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and I can get it like

```
@Autowire protected MessageSource resource;
```

but when I try to get it from app context with casting to MessageSource I get a cast exception

how is autowire and getting bean from app context different ?

```
(MessageSource) _applicationContext.getBean(name);

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource cannot be cast to org.springframework.context.MessageSource
```

it implements the interface, why it cannot be cast to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet it's a classloader issue, it's very likely that you are using a different classloader for loading that bean. Because there is no other valid reason for this to happen.